# How to fix adafruit 7" display resolution problem on PI3?

Tags: pi-3, display, touchscreen, config.txt, adafruit

I recently bought adafruit 7" display to be used with my PI3 to see if it will work. Well, it sort of works. The screen comes up everything is displayed but the resolution is screwed up. I have tried several things, but none of them helped. Here is how my display looks like.
[image]

I tried to adjust the resolution to get rid of the white bar in the config.txt, but all it does is shrink the area that is active making everything look so tiny. However, the white bar never goes away. Being lost and at the end of all that I can do I enabled the experimental GL display driver in the raspberry pi configuration. This expanded the screen to the actual size of the display such that I can no longer see the taskbar and touchscreen doesn't work. In other word, taskbar is somewhere all in the bottom of the screen beyond the edge of the Display. I came across an information that I have to adjust the resolution in the config.txt to fix this, but I don't know how. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: these two statements contradict each other .... `This expanded the screen to the actual size of the display` .... `taskbar is somewhere all in the bottom of the screen beyond the edge of the Display`

Comment: @jsotola When I enable the experimental display driver, PI treats the adafruit display as if it is a FULL UP monitor. So, what is shown in the adafruit display is portion of the desktop from top left-hand corner to the bottom right-hand corner of the display and the taskbar is nowhere to be seen on the adafruit display. I assume it is actually located way beyond the bottom edge of the adafruit display. However, when I just adjust the resolution in the `config.txt` file, it just shrinks everything down making it tiny, but the white bar you see to the right never goes away.